# DIV-Positioning wrong

Tags: javascript, html, alignment

The idea is the following, if you click on a button for "show", an ajax-request will start, and the response will take place in a (hidden) `<div>`, and the `<div>` will come visible.

But the `<div>` gets placed wrong. it is in a `<tr>`, and should appear in it, between 1.1 and 1.2

Here is a fiddle, where i made an example, without the Ajax, it just display's/hide's the text "TEST"

http://jsfiddle.net/pt2w3/12/

How can this be solved correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the cell (`<td></td>`):

```
<Label onclick="doShow()"> <p> ---- CLICK ME (show) ----- </p> </label>
<Label onclick="doHide()"> <p> ---- CLICK ME (hide) ----- </p> </label>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th> TITLE 1 </th>
        <th> TITLE 2 </th>
        <th> TITLE 3 </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td> 1.1</td>
              <td> 2.1</td>
              <td> 3.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="class1" id="testdiv"><h1>TEST</h1> </div></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 1.2</td>
              <td> 2.2</td>
              <td> 3.2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/pt2w3/13/

Answer (score 0):

It is *invalid* to place a `div` immediately inside a `tr`. You need to nest the `div` within a valid child of the `tr` instead. Otherwise, the browser will place the invalid element elsewhere, in this case it is positioning it before the table.

When in doubt, check the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element). Specifically, check the *Contexts in which this element can be used* to know where you can place an element, and the *Content model* portion to understand what you can place immediately within that element:

[image]

Comment: so i have to review my `<div>` content, because it the ajax Responses directly a `<td> 1234</td>`. So, this would require a complete `<table>` conainter right?

Comment: @user3108507 If your response starts with a `<td>`, you would need to only print that immediately within a `tr` [as the specification instructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element). It's usually best to *not* send HTML in your AJAX. Just send data, and apply templates to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<td></td>` tag to make the div display correctly:

Fiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/pt2w3/14/

html

```
<Label onclick="doShow()"> <p> ---- CLICK ME (show) ----- </p> </label>
<Label onclick="doHide()"> <p> ---- CLICK ME (hide) ----- </p> </label>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th> TITLE 1 </th>
        <th> TITLE 2 </th>
        <th> TITLE 3 </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td> 1.1</td>
              <td> 2.1</td>
              <td> 3.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="class1" id="testdiv"><h1>TEST</h1> </div></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 1.2</td>
              <td> 2.2</td>
              <td> 3.2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Rendered like so:

---- CLICK ME (show) -----

---- CLICK ME (hide) -----

TITLE 1 
         TITLE 2 
         TITLE 3 
    
    
          
               1.1
               2.1
               3.1

## TEST

1.2
               2.2
               3.2